# How do I clone a sub-folder of a repository in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, clone, dvcs

I have a Mercurial repository containing a handful of related projects. I want to branch just one of these projects to work on it elsewhere.

Is cloning just part of a repository possible, and is that the right way to achieve this?

Comment: From what I've heard, this is one reason to not put several projects in one repo.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

What you want is a [**narrow** or **partial** clone](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PartialClone), but this is unfortunately not yet supported.

If you already have a big repository and you realize that it would make sense to split it into several smaller repositories, then you can use the [convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial) to do a **Mercurial to Mercurial conversion**. Note that this creates a **new** repository `foo` and you cannot push/pull between `your-big-repo` and `foo`.

The `convert extension` is not enabled by default so add the following to your repo's `hgrc` file or your `mercurial.ini` file:

```
[extensions]
hgext.convert=
```

Then create a `map.txt` file with

```
include "libs/foo"
rename "libs/foo" .
```

(note you can use forward slashes even on Windows) and run

```
$ hg convert --filemap map.txt your-big-repo foo
```

That will make `foo` a repository with the full history of the `libs/foo` folder from `your-big-repo`.

If you want to delete all evidence of `foo` from `your-big-repo` you can make another conversion where you use `exclude libs/foo` to get rid of the directory.

When you have several repositories like that and you want to use them as a whole, then you should look at [subrepositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository). This feature lets you include other repositories in a checkout — similarly to how `svn:externals` work. Please follow the [recommendations](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository#Recommendations) on that wiki page.

Comment: Thanks - I've found a workaround for what I need to do. Interesting to see the issues involved.

Comment: Argh! "I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of this, which this margin is too narrow to contain."

Comment: ok, if cloning of subdir is done, how would you merge changes back in the original directory?

Comment: @martin-geisler these days [narrow and partial cloning are concepts that are part of Mercurial itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40355673/110204). I [tried to update your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23765444) but was told the change was "intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit" so hence this comment.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of doing a partial clone, you can use the [Convert Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) to split your repo into more than one repo by sub repository.

Specifically, see the section, [Converting from Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial):

> It's also useful to filter Mercurial repositories to get subsets of an existing one. For example to transform a subdirectory subfoo of a repository foo into a repository with its own life (while keeping its full history), do the following:
>
> ```
> $ echo include subfoo > /tmp/myfilemap
> $ echo rename subfoo . >> /tmp/myfilemap
> $ hg convert --filemap /tmp/myfilemap /path/to/repo/foo /tmp/mysubfoo-repo
> ```

Answer (score 6):

I've stumbled accross this issue and found one way to do it: Using symlinks (Linux only unfortunately)

For example, if you only need `/project` in the repository, on your computer clone the repo in another folder, then use `ln -s /repo/location/ project`. Mercurial will handle it

Answer (score 5):

(Late 2016) Mainline Mercurial still doesn't package support for "narrow clones" but there are third party extensions that tackle the problem in different ways.

If you can cope with just a narrow *checkout* (aka "sparse checkout" or "partial checkout by file path") then Facebook's `sparse.py` extension from the [hg-experimental repository](https://bitbucket.org/facebook/hg-experimental) (look inside the `hgext3rd/` directory) may be workable. In this scenario, you still clone the full history (thus the .hg directory is no smaller) but your working directory only shows/acts on a subset of the full repository.

Alternatively Google have created a [NarrowHG extension](https://bitbucket.org/Google/narrowhg) that does narrow *cloning* (aka "partial cloning by file path"). You will need to be in control of the server, the client and be willing to use experimental features but it really does restrict the clone's copied history in .hg to a subset of what was in the original repository.

(2019) The [`sparse` extension was merged into Mercurial 4.3](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew/Archive#Mercurial_4.3_.2F_4.3.1_.282017-08-10.29) as the experimental [`sparse` extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/doc/hg.1.html#sparse). The [NarrowHG extension was merged into Mercurial 4.6](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew/Archive#Mercurial_4.6_.282018-05-06.29) as the `hgext.narrow` extension.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible, `hg clone` will clone the whole repository.

You can take a look a the sub-repository extension that allows you to have repositories inside a repository, which might match your needs.

Answer (score 2):

This is straight forward with the [Convert extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial).

Comment: My guess is that it's because the solution doesn't really let you clone a subdirectory from a repository. Instead, it let's you convert an existing repository into a new and smaller repository that you can then clone.

Comment: 1) As stated above you're not answering the question the original question asked.
2) You don't explain that what the original question asked is impossible.  You just offer something different.
3) You give a link, instead of actually explaining.

Comment: @MartinGeisler just to note, while the convert solution can be named a bit differently from what one would call a partial clone, it allows one to do anything a partial clone would allow, including pushing to the remote repository and pulling from it AFAIK. I believe you know this but I am posting this note mostly for eventual future readers :)

Comment: @brandizzi: The converted repo will have new changeset IDs, so you cannot push back to the original. What you _can_ do is to repeatedly convert the original repository and pull from the converted into your existing partial clones. That allows you to keep in sync with development in a big repo, but it is a one-way strategy where you need to manually (using, say, `hg export`) copy changes back to the original repo.

Comment: @MartinGeisler actually, you can! You just need to use the `-f` flag. See [this script](http://pastebin.com/HhZLyv2T) as an example. (*Note*: requires the convert and graphlog extensions.)

Comment: @brandizzi yes and no :) After `hg push -f`, you end up with not only multiple heads, but also _multiple roots_. This is because the root nodes of the two repositories differ and `hg push -f` will thus copy all data from your partial clone to the full clone. The `--filemap` argument should be `f` in your paste and after fixing that you get [this output](http://pastebin.com/WKixSRis). The `Created` commit is duplicated and that is probably not how you want the main repository to look like.

Comment: @MartinGeisler fair enough, one has to have those shortcomings in mind! I was not aware of them, actually (well, I knew it would create multiple roots but it did not bother me). BTW, what would be the greatest practical problems on having multiple roots?

Comment: @brandizzi: your main repository is grossly affected by the "partial" clone and that's normally not acceptable for real repositories. You end up with duplicate data for all revisions touching the subdirectory you "partially" clone. You should write to mercurial@selenic.com if you want to discuss this further, StackOverflow is not really meant for discussion.