# book for intermediate to advanced Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I'm looking for a book (or equivalent) to help me go from using hg to basically do the same things I do with svn to using hg as it was really intended. It should cover the internals and how to extend hg etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have looked into Mercurial a little and i find the resources online are very good. Here is a link to a good resource and a Book as well (Online and Print versions)

[Mercurial: The Definitive Guide](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/)

Answer (score 4):

Joel Spolsky released [Hg Init: a Mercurial tutorial](http://hginit.com/) recently. It looks nice and easy to read.

> Mercurial is a modern, open source, distributed version control system, and a compelling upgrade from older systems like Subversion. In this user-friendly, six-part tutorial, Joel Spolsky teaches you the key concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Some Mercurial branching resources:

- [**A Guide to Branching in Mercurial**](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial/)
- [Mercurial: Named Branches vs Multiple Repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890723/mercurial-named-branches-vs-multiple-repositories)
- [Mercurial repository layout for multiple branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628332/mercurial-repository-layout-for-multiple-branches)

Answer (score 0):

Rob Conery just released 4 videos on [TekPub](http://tekpub.com/preview/hg). You should check em out. You can get access to all the vids on the site for 15 bucks.

Comment: The preview shows a lot of setting up Visual Studios and not a log about HG. Its hard to tell from the preview how detailed the full videos are. Do you have a ringing endorsement?

Comment: No endorsement dude. I'm a paying customer and have found them to be a excellent way to get moving faster than reading. Did you read the video summaries at the end of the page?

Comment: P.S. One caveat is that the site is geared more toward ASP.Net MVC and Rails developers... :)