# Can I clone part of a Mercurial repository?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

Is it possible to clone part of a Mercurial repository? Let's say the repository is quite large, or contains multiple projects, or multiple branches. Can I clone only part of the repository?

E.g. in Subversion, you might have `trunk` and `branches`. If I only want to get trunk (or one of the branches) I can just request `[project]/trunk`. If I clone the hg repo I'll get trunk and all of the branches. This might be a lot of information I don't want. Can I avoid getting this?

Alternatively, if I want to have multiple projects in one hg repo, how should I do this? I.e. so that I might just get one of the projects and ignore the others.

Comment: For future reference: Cloning part of a repository is called, in DVCS jargon, a "narrow clone" or "partial clone".  (Cloning only part of the *history* as opposed to the directory structure, is a "shallow clone".)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I clone a sub-folder of a repository in Mercurial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920355/how-do-i-clone-a-sub-folder-of-a-repository-in-mercurial)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes you can.  I'm sure you've moved on, but for the sake of those who will wander here later, I followed the docs at [ConvertExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension), and wrote a simple batch script:

```
@echo off
echo Converting %1
REM Create the file map
echo include %1 > ~myfilemap               
echo rename %1 . >> ~myfilemap 
REM Run the convert process
hg convert --filemap ~myfilemap .\ ..\%1   
REM Delete the file map
del ~myfilemap                             
cd ..\%1
REM update the new repo--to create the files
hg update
```

Name it something like `split.cmd`, and put it in the directory for the repo you want to split.  Say for example you have `C:\repos\ReallyBigProject`, and a subfolder is `C:\repos\ReallyBigProject\small-project`.  At the command prompt, run:

```
cd\repos\ReallyBigProject
split.cmd small-project
```

This will create `C:\repos\small-project` with a slice of the relevant history of revisions from the larger project.

The `convert` is not enabled by default.  You'll need to make sure the following lines exist in your `.hg\hgrc` file (`c:\repos\ReallyBigProject\.hg\hgrc` in my example):

```
[extensions]
hgext.convert=
```

Comment: See in particular http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial

Comment: I don't believe that this would allow you to push back any changes. You can export your local changes to patch files that you then import into a full local copy of upstream, but then that kind of defeats the point of the partial clone in the first place. Also, the OP didn't specifically say if he wanted a shallow clone (same tree, fewer revisions) or a partial clone (sub-tree, some or all revisions). In either case, convert will change the hashes.

Comment: Using convert will typically (or always?:) not produce a *clone* but a derivative copy which is "unrelated" to the original. That would totally inhibit pushing changes back to the source repo. Its useful, but not really what people may expect.

Answer (score 16):

To my knowledge, that's not possible. But compared to Subversrion, cloning the whole repos may not be slower than just a branch from SVN.

Quoting from [UnderstandingMercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/UnderstandingMercurial):

> Many SVN/CVS users expect to host
>   related projects together in one
>   repository. This is really not what hg
>   was made for, so you should try a
>   different way of working. This
>   especially means, that you cannot
>   check out only one directory of a
>   repository.
>
> If you absolutely need to host
>   multiple projects in a kind of
>   meta-repository though, you could try
>   the [Subrepositories](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/subrepos) feature that was
>   introduced with Mercurial 1.3 or the
>   older [ForestExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ForestExtension).

Comment: This is a pretty big omission since a lot hosting sites only offer one repo. With svn I can effectively have as many repos as I want by only taking one branch from the main one. The subrepos sound like a hack.

Comment: In a centralized point-of-view, that makes sense. But Mercurial and Git are decentralized. 1 project = 1 repos, that's the way it works.

Comment: @Nick: No, it sounds like those hosting providers don't understand distributed version control.

Comment: This is probably no longer true. `hg help clone` shows `-b  --branch BRANCH [+]  clone only the specified branch`. When cloned a repo this way when I type `hg branches` it show the only requested one.

Comment: OP asked about a specified directory within the repo, not a specified branch.

Answer (score 16):

@Nick

"E.g. in Subversion, you might have trunk and branches. If I only want to get trunk (or one of the branches) I can just request [project]/trunk. If I clone the hg repo I'll get trunk and all of the branches. This might be a lot of information I don't want. Can I avoid getting this?"

Absolutely.  Just use `hg clone -r <branch>` and get only the branch you want.  If you have lots of branches, you need a `-r <branch>` for each one.  `<branch>` doesn't have to be a named branch: you can simply have multiple unnamed heads (or named heads using bookmark, though those still aren't perfect, because currently they don't show up with push/pull/clone).

Keep in mind that in DVCSes, Mercurial among them, branches are often short-lived and merged back into each other frequently.  If you pull a branch you will still get the common history it has with any other branches.

Comment: Just a heads up it's -b for specifying a branch to clone (you can still use multiple -b <branch>), -r is used for specifying a changeset.

Answer (score 8):

@Nick said:

"This is a pretty big omission since a lot hosting sites only offer one repo. With svn I can effectively have as many repos as I want by only taking one branch from the main one. The subrepos sound like a hack."

Subrepos (aka submodules) are not as ideal as "narrow clones" its true.  But at least for having many distinct projects in one hosting site's repository, you can have multiple code-bases in one repository.  This won't allow you to slice up different sections of one repository / sub-directories of a project , but it *will* let you manage multiple projects.  What you do is have lots of named branches each rooted at the empty (or null) changeset (i.e. they have no common root revision).  It can get a little messy to track the branches but it does work.

For example:

```
hg init
hg branch project-1
# Changes, commits, repeated as needed
hg update null
hg branch project-2
# Changes, commits, repeated as needed
```

You now can see all your projects:

```
> hg branches
project-2                      5:42c2beffe780
project-1                      2:43fd60024328
```

The projects are unrelated (though you can merge them):

```
> hg debugancestors
-1:000000000000
```

Most usefully: you can clone only the project you want, and the others won't mix in:

```
> hg clone <repository> -r project-1
```

The graph for this would look something like this (`hg log -qG`):

```
@  5 | project-2 | {tip}
|
o  4 | project-2
|
o  3 | project-2

o  2 | project-1
|
o  1 | project-1
|
o  0 | project-1
```

You can do this for as many projects as you need, listing each with `hg branches`, and jumping between them with `hg update`.  This takes *some* care, because named branch support isn't perfect.  It isn't always intuitive for one thing (read about `hg clone -u` in Mercurial 1.4 -- the pre-1.4 behavior is surprising when cloning).  But it *does* work.

Comment: Yes, the cool thing is you can create a new project whenever you want by updating to the revision 0 and commit in a new branch from here.

But the clone command will still clone the whole repos, am I right?

Comment: @Savageman: Doesn't have to.  Use `hg clone -r <branch>` and you will get only the given branch.  If you want the whole set of projects, `hg clone` will do what you want, yes.

Answer (score 5):

Mercurial and Git only permit cloning on the entire repository.  Thus it is recommended that each project gets its own repository.

Mercurial has a [`forest` extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ForestExtension) to ease having a "forest" for project repositories.  The extension keeps each project in a separate repository, but provides options to update/push/pull all the forest repositories together.

Comment: But even subrepos seem to be experimental in 1.3. This is a pretty big omission for me.

Comment: @Nick: sounds like you're fighting the DVCS instead of working with it. Take some time to learn how it wants to work and you'll quickly realise the benefits.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to ask Mercurial to clone just a branch using `hg clone -r branchname` (see [Mercurial clone from a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547251/mercurial-clone-from-a-branch)).

With Google's [NarrowHG extension](https://bitbucket.org/Google/narrowhg) extension it's possible to perform a narrow clone (see [How do I clone a sub-folder of a repository in Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920355/how-do-i-clone-a-sub-folder-of-a-repository-in-mercurial) for a similar question).

Answer (score 1):

I know that it is nearly 10 years after this question was asked, I I stumbled across
this question by accident.

There is a new mercurial extension call sparse that allows you to do this.

Comment: The `sparse.py` extension only makes *narrow checkouts* possible (which doesn't impact the history fetched) whereas the question is talking about not fetching branches. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40355673/2732969 for some further discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible improvement to Vadim Kotov's solution that supports spaces in the `small-project` name/subfolder:

```
@echo off
echo Converting "%~1"
REM Create the file map
echo include "%~1" > ~myfilemap               
echo rename "%~1" . >> ~myfilemap 
REM Run the convert process
hg convert --filemap ~myfilemap .\ "..\%~1"
REM Delete the file map
del ~myfilemap                             
cd ".\%~1"
REM update the new repo--to create the files
hg update
```