# Copy a single branch to a different repository

Tags: mercurial

We have this mercurial remote repository (lets call it repo01):

```
A --- B --- C --- D (default)
       \
        --- E --- F (other)
```

We need to grant access to the E-F branch to our client, but not the A-D one. On the other hand we need to keep track of changes to the E-F branch. So I was thinking that if we could somehow copy the E-F branch to a different remote repository, we could achieve just that.

So the other remote repository (let's call it repo02) would look like this:

```
E --- F (other)
```

Then we would work with both repositories and the client would just work with repo02. The question is, can this actually be done and if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is the combination of these two questions:

- [Mercurial clone from a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547251/mercurial-clone-from-a-branch)
- [Can I clone just the latest changesets of a repository instead of the entire history?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21762447/6394138)

If you were going to copy the entire history of the branch `other` then you would just need to provide the `-b` option to `hg clone`:

```
hg clone http://your/repo -b other
```

For your purposes, you must combine it with some way of creating a shallow clone, which Mercurial doesn't natively support. Look at the extensions suggested in the top two answers to the second question above (https://bitbucket.org/facebook/remotefilelog and https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ShallowClone).