# Mercurial sparse checkout

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension, sparse-checkout

In this [F8 conference video](https://youtu.be/X0VH78ye4yY?t=8m40s)(starting 8:40) from 2015 they speak about the advantages of using Mercurial and a single repository across facebook.

How does this work in practice? Using Mercurial, can i checkout a subdirectory (live in SVN)? If so, how? Do i need a [facebook-mercurial-extension](https://bitbucket.org/facebook/hg-experimental) for this

P.S.: I only found answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586824/partial-clone-with-git-and-mercurial#answer-2587100) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114726/check-out-only-a-directory-from-mercurial) from 2010 on SO where i am not sure if the answers still apply with all the efforts FB put into it.

Comment: This sheds some light on how it works: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial-devel/2014-June/059425.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your question it is not clear if you are looking for a workflow (the monorepo vs multiple repos debate) or for performance and scaling for a *huge* code base.

For the workflow, I suggest googling for `monorepo`. It has its pros and cons, you need to understand your situation and current workflow to decide. For the performance and scaling, keep reading.

The idea of `remotefilelog` is not to checkout a subdirectory (as you mention), the idea is to checkout everything. In order to do that in an efficient way, you need two extensions actively developed by Facebook:

- [remotefilelog](https://bitbucket.org/facebook/hg-experimental/). This gives you something conceptually similar to a shallow clone. This reduces `hg clone` and `hg pull` time.
- [fsmonitor](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FsMonitorExtension) (previously called `hgwatchman`, it is now part of mercurial core). This dramatically reduces time of local operations such as `hg status`. Note that `fsmonitor` is independent from `remotefilelog`. You can start experimenting with this, since it doesn't require any setup on the server side.

With a recent mercurial (which I strongly suggest) you can shave off the additional startup time of the Python interpreter using [CommandServer](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommandServer) + [CHg](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CHg).

Some additional notes:

- I tested extensively `fsmonitor`. It works very well, on huge repos the time of `hg status` is reduced from 10 secs to less than 1 sec (and the majority of this 1 sec is Python startup time, see above for `CHg`). If your repository is really huge, you might need to fine tune some inotify kernel parameters (or the equivalent on MacOSX). The `fsmonitor` documentation has all the information you need.
- I didn't test `remotefilelog`, although I read everything I found about it and I am sure it works. Depending on how development is done (everybody has always Internet connectivity or not, the organization has its own master repo or not) there can be a caveat: it partially transforms the decentralized `hg` into a centralized VCS like `svn`: some operations that normally can be done offline (for example: `hg log` and the first `hg update` to a changeset in the past) will now require connectivity to the master repository.
- Before considering `remotefilelog`, I used extensively the `largefiles` extension on a huge repo. It has the same drawbacks than `remotefilelog` and some confusing corner cases for users that want to use `hg` just to get things done without taking the time to understand how it works. If I were to manage another huge repo, I would use `remotefilelog` instead than `largefiles`, although their use case is not really the same.
- Mercurial has also support for `subrepositories` ([doc1](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository), [doc2](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/)). The problem is that it changes the behavior of hg depending on where you are in the source tree. Again, if the developers don't care about really understanding how hg works, it will be just too confusing.

Additional information:

- [Facebook Engineering blog post](https://code.facebook.com/posts/218678814984400/scaling-mercurial-at-facebook/)
- [scaling mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ScaleMercurial) wiki, although not completely up to date
- just by googling `mercurial facebook`.

Answer (score 0):

> i am not sure if the answers still apply with all the efforts FB put
>   into it

(Early 2017) The answers in the questions linked still apply (because they occasionally get updated) but note that you will have to read all the comments and answers.

remotefilelog essentially allows on demand shallow clones (so you don't fetch the *history* for everything for all time) but you still fetch the essential metadata for, and checkout across, all the directories of the repo at the desired revision.

> Using Mercurial, can i checkout a subdirectory (li[k]e in SVN)? If so, how?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40355673/7836056 discusses how you might use third party extensions to allow narrow/sparse checkouts (Facebook's `sparse.py`) or narrow clones (Google's NarrowHG) with Mercurial thus only "creating" a single directory from within the main repository (albeit with radically different tradeoffs).

(Note phrasing matters: "sparse checkout" means a very specific action when referring to distributed version control in a manner that doesn't exist when using it to refer to centralised version control)