# Partial download by filepath with mercurial

Tags: mercurial

How do you download a specific folder from a Mercurial repo? This is a similar question to [partial cloning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586824/partial-clone-with-git-and-mercurial), but I don't want to actually create a local repo, since I won't be versioning these files. I just want to quickly download a specific folder containing a few KB worth of files from a repo that's several hundreds MB in size.

Specifically, I want to download all the entire "[examples/plugins](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e01e520d15603b87efaffa26817bf6224f00f320/examples/plugins/?at=gazebo_2.2)" folder from the [Gazebo project](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/).

I've tried searching hg's manpage and Google, but all my searches keep bringing me back to pages that assume I want to create a full repo and make a [partial clone](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PartialClone) or [narrow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328132/is-it-possible-to-checkout-a-single-directory-from-a-mercurial-hg-repository), which hg doesn't support.

Comment: Sounds like you want `hg archive`, but for a remote repo and that isn't supported either (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2351128)).

Answer (score 1):

If the Mercurial repository is running hgweb, it's possible to download a specific folder remotely. For example for the official hg repository, you can download https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/archive/REVISION.tar.bz2/SUBPATH/.

Example: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/archive/19c5b0913960.tar.bz2/contrib/

This uses the 'hg archive' functionality Edward mentions, but through the web-interface.