# Clone One Project from Solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mercurial

I'm working with mercurial and the plugin for visual studio, I have a solution with many projects under source control. My problem is that I need to clone just one project because I need to personalize this one for many clients. Is there a way I can do this?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot clone only a single directory from a Mercurial repository — you always have to clone the full repository. You should therefore make sure to have a 1–1 mapping between repositories and projects.

FYI, such a clone would be called a [narrow clone](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4691286/110204) and it's not supported yet.